# SSIS Set Destination Table Name

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS Package that needs to load data through an oledb component into a table whose name is not known until runtime. In the oledb destination editor I have selected "Data access mode" as "Table name or view name variable". I have entered my "Variable name" that holds the name of the table. When I hit the preview button I am presented with a preview of the correct table. However, when I attempt to run / debug the package I get the following message at the validation stage - before the package even attempts to run:

```
Information: 0x4004300A at Check Recs and Insert, DTS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.

Error: 0xC0202042 at Check Recs and Insert, Insert Into TransactionX table [2269]: A destination table name has not been provided.
Error: 0xC004706B at Check Recs and Insert, DTS.Pipeline: "component "Insert Into TransactionX table" (2269)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
Error: 0xC004700C at Check Recs and Insert, DTS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Check Recs and Insert: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "PointsPartnerImport.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

It says `A destination table name has not been provided.` but it has! Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Did you tried by setting the delay validation property of "TRUE" and run the package? Since, your are passing the destination table dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

What programmatic format are the data in?  I had a similar problem today trying to import data from an Excel spreadsheet.  It turned out that the spreadsheet's name had a " " (physical white space) in it. SSIS wasn't too happy about that. But for whatever reason, the problem resolved itself after I replaced that white space with an _ (underscore).

As to why, my guess is certain characters should generally be avoided in titles such as white spaces or hyphens. There may be characters in addition to the white space that give a similar error (hyphens?).

Answer (score 0):

Are u setting the variable to a default value? Check this article out: [msdn thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sqlintegrationservices/thread/b876cc8e-2ae3-452d-b18b-e2552ebf118a)

Comment: I have given the variable a default value. My problem is not the same as that given in the msdn thread. In my case the problem only appears at runtime. The variable is populated in the "Control Flow" but I have set the scope to that of the package os I guess it should be visible from the "Data Flow"?

Comment: If you set the scope to the package level, then the value within the variable should be recognized throughtout the whole package-control flow, data flow, event handlers, etc. Maybe try creating a completely new package from scratch and see if that fixes your problem? I have never had issues doing the very same thing you are doing in the past...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the Variable name has a default value and it matches the first sheet name in your Excel workbook. SSIS needs to load the first worksheet during design time, you cannot skip this validation.
2. Spaces or special characters in the Sheet name will not affect the functionality.